# how to merge svn repos into one git repo with clean history?

Tags: git, visual-studio, svn, azure-devops, git-svn

I'm trying to merge several svn repo into one git repo and push it on a new remote azure repo. I achieved to do that with git svn and  git subtrees but when I browse the history on Azure DevOps it's messy. All the svn commits are visible on the global history of my repo but not on the files history itself.
If I check one file history, I can't find the related svn commits.
However if I clone my remote azure repo on my local, I can find the proper history in visual studio.
What I see on Azure is different from what I see on my local. How can I get the history right on Azure DevOps ? Hope my problem is understandable.
Thanks.

Comment: Think about a new start with git and a clean new merged repository. You could keep your SVN server read only online, for the old history.

Comment: I think that might be a solution ... I found out what I'm trying to do is not possible.Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

> how to merge svn repos into one git repo with clean history?

This seems to be a warning that might appear when merging multiple `svn` repos into one `git` repos.

> Althought commits from boths sides are retained, showing per file
>   history does not return what you'd expect.
>
> Traversing the full history of either of the two repositories is still
>   possible though.

You could get the details info from this post [Migrating multiple SVN repos into a single GIT repo ?](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Fisheye-Crucible-questions/Migrating-multiple-SVN-repos-into-a-single-GIT-repo/qaq-p/4960).

Personally, Mar's suggestion is a more reasonable suggestion. You can consider doing it as that.

Hope this helps.